# Javascript-Setting background image of a DIV via a function and function parameter

Tags: javascript, html, css, url

I have the following HTML:

```
<div id="tab1" style="position:relative; background-image:url(buttons/off.png);
    <a href="javascript:ChangeBackgroundImageOfTab('tab1', 'on');">
        <img id="DivBtn1" name="DivBtn1" src="buttons/text.png" >
    </a>
</div>
```

and the following Javascript:

```
function ChangeBackgroungImageOfTab(tabName, imagePrefix)
{
    document.getElementById(tabName).style.background-image= 'url("buttons/" + imagePrefix + ".png")';
}
```

The issue arises when i try to set the tabs background image via a call to getElementByID - I do now know how to create a dynamic URL that uses the parameter that was passed in, along with some other hard coded values.  In this case, we are swapping the OFF background image with the ON background image.

How can i do this?  Is there some way to use a javascript variable, assign the full path to it, then send it into the call as the background image path?

Comment: How is the parameter being passed in?

Comment: Through this call : <a href="javascript:ChangeBackgroundImageOfTab('tab1', 'on');">  - It is just a string.  when the user clicks on the image inside of the link node, the function gets called and the value of 'on' gets sent into the function, signifying we need to change the background image of the parent div to on.png

Comment: @RienNeVaPlus yes typo, will correct asap

Comment: you have incorrectly formatted the image path it should be 'url("buttons/" ' + imagePrefix  + ' ".png")';

Comment: You'll also want to use `style.backgroundImage`, not `style.background-image`.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You need to concatenate your string.

```
document.getElementById(tabName).style.backgroundImage = 'url(buttons/' + imagePrefix + '.png)';
```

The way you had it, it's just making 1 long string and not actually interpreting imagePrefix.

I would even suggest creating the string separate:

```
function ChangeBackgroungImageOfTab(tabName, imagePrefix)
{
    var urlString = 'url(buttons/' + imagePrefix + '.png)';
    document.getElementById(tabName).style.backgroundImage =  urlString;
}
```

As mentioned by David Thomas below, you can ditch the double quotes in your string. Here is a little article to get a better idea of how strings and quotes/double quotes are related: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/strings.html

Comment: Why are the `"` being included within the string? And I hadn't seen until now, but you can't have `-` in a property, or variable, name (it'll be interpreted as an operator), use camel-case: `backgroundColor`.

Comment: creating the string seperatly worked.  putting it inline didnt work, but compiled and ran correctly with no errors. thanks for the help!

Comment: Cool. Some people think that creating your string separate like this is creating more code. I find doing this helps with debugging, as I can then see exactly whats going to be assigned using the ol' console.log. :)

Comment: @TyMayn totally.  i agree.  so much easier for debugging, when you can just hover over a variable instead of typing it into the console or the immediate window.

Answer (score 9):

From what I know, the correct syntax is:

```
function ChangeBackgroungImageOfTab(tabName, imagePrefix)
{
    document.getElementById(tabName).style.backgroundImage = "url('buttons/" + imagePrefix + ".png')";
}
```

So basically, `getElementById(tabName).backgroundImage` and split the string like:

```
"cssInHere('and" + javascriptOutHere + "/cssAgain')";
```

Comment: getelementbyId doesnt need #divname only name of the id without #

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a direct approach and using a `local` File in that case.
Try

```
<div
style={{ background-image: 'url(' + Image + ')', background-size: 'auto' }}
/>
```

This is the case of `JS` with inline styling where `Image` is a local file that you must have imported with a path.