# Display image after select with javascript

Tags: javascript, css, image

I made JS for displaying an image after selecting it. Here is the code

html code

```
<input type="file" id="file_photo" onchange="preview_image(event)" name="item_image"  ></input>
<img id='output_image'/>
```

JS code

```
function preview_image(event){

    document.getElementById('output_image').style.display='block';
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(){
        var output = document.getElementById('output_image');
        output.src = reader.result;
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);
};
```

It success to display. But the question is, could I put the output image inside css url background image?

If the html is like this.

```
<label for="file_photo" class="file">  
   <div class="camera_icon" style="background: url() center center no-repeat #d7d7d7;background-size: cover;">
         <img src="/public/img/stock/icon07.png">
         <img src="/public/img/stock/icon06.png" class="plus_icon">
    </div>
    <input type="file" id="file_photo" onchange="preview_image(event)" name="item_image"  ></input>
 </label>
```

could I put the output image in

```
style="background: url() center center no-repeat #d7d7d7;background-size: cover;"
```

because I need to follow the css file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript-Setting background image of a DIV via a function and function parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18665702/javascript-setting-background-image-of-a-div-via-a-function-and-function-paramet)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working fiddle for you mate : http://jsfiddle.net/qvxg6ok4/12/

You need to assign a formulated URl property for div's background image with the data url you are getting from the file control.

```
output.style.backgroundImage = "url('" + reader.result + "')"
```

This fiddle is with searching with class name : http://jsfiddle.net/qvxg6ok4/14/

Answer (score 1):

You need to have the path/src for the image you want to apply.

and then you may user the following code

document.getElementById('camera_icon').style.backgroundImage="url({{images/img.jpg}})";

Try using this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/LvsYc/15724/

```
    <label for="file_photo" class="file">  
   <div class="camera_icon" id="camera_icon">
         <img src="/public/img/stock/icon07.png">
         <img src="/public/img/stock/icon06.png" class="plus_icon">
    </div>
    <input type="file" id="file_photo" name="item_image"  ></input>
 </label>
    <style>
    .camera_icon {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-color:#d7d7d7;
  background-position: center center;
  height:300px;
}
    </style>
    <script>
    function readURL(input) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function (e) {
                //$('#blah').attr('src', e.target.result);
                document.getElementById('camera_icon').style.backgroundImage="url( " + e.target.result + ")";
            }

            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }

    $("#file_photo").change(function(){
        readURL(this);
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: thank you guys for helping me.. i really appreciate it so much!!

Answer (score 0):

have you tried like this,

```
function preview_image(event){

document.getElementsByClassName('camera_icon').style.display='block';
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function(){
    var output = document.getElementsByClassName('camera_icon');
    output.style.backgroundImage= reader.result;
}
reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);
};
```

use background image instead of src of image

Comment: Are you not supposed to get array of objects matching "getElementsByClassName" ?

Comment: And the data url is not going to work with simple assignment to backgroundimage. And on top of that, there is no such property for an object