# How to dynamically set background image url in CSS using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I've been trying to make this work for a little while now.

I thought the following code would work since I'm getting the value from the input and setting the background-image URL to said value.

Thanks!

The code inside of the head tag.

```
<script  type="text/javascript">

 function loadImg() {

  var imageUrl = $('#hostImage').attr('value')

  document.getElementById("upload-success-bg").style.backgroundImage=imageUrl

}

</script>

<style>

 #upload-success-bg {
 background-image: url();
 }

</style>
```

Input field code

```
<div class="status">

 <input class="image-url" type="text" id="hostImage" name="hostImage" required="true" 
 value="URL LOADS HERE">

</div>
```

Where I would like to the image to show

```
<div class="dropzone upload-success" id="upload-success-bg">
            <div class="info"><p>Drag image file here</p><p>Or click here to select image</p></div>
<input type="file" required="" class="input" accept="image/*"></div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript-Setting background image of a DIV via a function and function parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18665702/javascript-setting-background-image-of-a-div-via-a-function-and-function-paramet)

Comment: Two issues are if the code is within `<head>` element the element does not yet exist in the `DOM`, and the function does not appear to be called in the JavaScript at the question. In addition to CSS `url()` function not being used to set the value of `background-image` property.

Comment: What do you mean by _"Where I would like to the image to show"_? What is the purpose of the `<input type="text">` element, and how is the`.value` of that element related to the `<input type="file">` element and displaying an image?

Comment: @guest271314 The div "dropzone upload-success" is where a user drags an image file to upload. When a user uploads an image, the URL of the image becomes the value of <input type="text">. I want to take this url and make it the background of the dropzone div.

Comment: @machina The `<input type="text">` element is not necessary. A `File` object does not have a URL property. A `Blob URL` or `data URL` can be created which points to the uploaded file. A `Blob URL`s lifetime is linked to the `document` which created the URL. A `data URL` represented a `data:`, `MIME` type, possibly `<charset>` `<base64|text>` encoding of the file.

Answer (score 5):

If you wish to use an URL for `backgound` and `background-color` CSS properties you have to use the `url()` syntax even within javascript, so changing your code to the following should work:

```
document.getElementById("upload-success-bg").style.backgroundImage = "url(" + imageUrl + ")"
```

Answer (score 2):

In jquery, you can do it this way:

```
 function loadImg() {

  var imageUrl = $('#hostImage').attr('value')

  $("#upload-success-bg").css("background-image", "url(" + imageUrl + ")");

}
```

Answer (score 1):

A `File` object does not have a URL property. A `Blob URL` or `data URL` can be created which points to the uploaded file. A `Blob URL`s lifetime is linked to the `document` which created the URL. A [`data URL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs) string

```
data:[<mediatype>][;base64],<data>
```

can be opened at a different `window` or browser.

You can use `FileReader` to convert `File` object to a `data URL` and set the `<input type="text">` `value` to the `FileReader` instance `result`.

```js
const input = document.querySelector("#file");
const [label] = input.labels;
const upload = document.querySelector("#upload-success-bg");
const uploadURL = document.querySelector("#hostImage");
const reader = new FileReader();

reader.addEventListener("load", e => {
  const {result} = reader;
  upload.style.backgroundImage = `url(${result})`;
  hostImage.style.width = `calc(${result.length}px)`;
  hostImage.value = result;
});

input.addEventListener("change", e => {
  const [file] = input.files;
  console.log(file)
  if (file && /^image/.test(file.type)) {
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  }
});
```

```css
#file {
  display: none;
}

label[for="file"] {
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropzone upload-success" id="upload-success-bg">
  <label class="info" for="file">
    Drag image file here
    Or click here to select image
  </label>
  <input type="file" required="" id="file" class="input" accept="image/*"></div>
<div class="status">
  <input class="image-url" type="text" id="hostImage" name="hostImage" required="true" readonly="true" value="URL LOADS HERE">
</div>
```

Comment: I should've mentioned I'm using a script with Imgur API that when a user selects a file, it uploads to Imgur and returns the image URL.

Comment: @machina See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. That does not affect the code at the answer. You can include the code which performs the asynchronous task within `FileReader` `load` event handler and set `hostImage.value` to the response text.

Comment: @machina `(async() => {
  try {
    const request = await fetch("/path/to/server", {method:"POST", body:file});
    const result = await request.text();
    upload.style.backgroundImage = \`url(${result})\`;
   hostImage.style.width = \`calc(${result.length}px)\`;
   hostImage.value = result;
   } catch(e) {console.error(e)}
})()`